# How do I confirm if mailparse PECL extension is installed AND enabled?

Tags: php

I installed the mailparse PECL extension and asked my hosting company to confirm that it is installed, and they said it is.

However, I keep getting this error below, which is saying a mailparse function is undefined, which makes me think it is NOT installed and/or enabled.

I ran `phpinfo()` and also `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` and while I do see mbstring listed (that is a prerequesite or mailparse), I don't see any mention of mailparse anywhere when I do either of those.

Does that confirm that it is in fact NOT installed or enabled?  Just seeking some direction here since I'm at a total standstill bc my hosting company told me it is installed and they can't support mailparse questions any further.

Thank you.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMimeMailParser\mailparse_msg_parse_file() in /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser/src/Parser.php:106 Stack trace: #0 /home/mysite/public_html/email-to-database.php(13): PhpMimeMailParser\Parser->setPath('path/to/mail.tx...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser/src/Parser.php on line 106

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_loaded_extensions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) to return all the modules compiled in and loaded in the PHP interpreter.

Look for `mailparse` in the list.

```php
<?php

foreach (get_loaded_extensions() as $module){
  echo "{$module}\n";
};
```